# Valid way of fetching data in a backbone collection and displaying the view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have the following code inside a previously rendered base view, i was wondering if this is the correct way to fetch data from a collection and render the view on success?

```
    var self = this;
    var c = new UserData.Collection();

            var ud = new UserData.View({
                collection:c
            });

            c.fetch({

                success: function(){

                    self.region_user_data.show(ud);

                }

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly better way using a promise instead of inlining the call back.

```
var self = this;
var c = new UserData.Collection();

var ud = new UserData.View({
    collection:c
});

var p = c.fetch();

p.done(function() {
    self.region_user_data.show(ud);
});
```